# What is the best Workflow for Updating a Web App

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I'm pretty new at this but I recently deployed my first web application using Django, Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Digital Ocean.

I went to make some updates and ran `sudo service gunicorn restart` to see the changes.  I wiped my entire Database.  I obviously need to work on setting up a better workflow for deploying to production.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  What are some best practises when re-deploying a Django App with a Postgres DB?  I've read some articles about backing up my DB (which I'm definitely going to be doing in future), but what else can be done to ensure a seem-less transition?

Comment: Restarting `gunicorn` would not wipe the database. Did you mean you manually wiped it?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  I restarted gunicorn and nginx and after that I lost all data associated with my models.  Is there anyway I could check what happened?